# binding dropdownlist to array asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, binding

I've hit a snag with the following code.

```
Dim dates As New ArrayList()
   Dim BWE1 As New ListItem(FirstBWEEndDateTextBox.Text, FirstBWEEndDateTextBox.Text)
   Dim BWE2 As New ListItem(SecondBWEEndDateTextBox.Text, SecondBWEEndDateTextBox.Text)
   Dim BWE3 As New ListItem(txtThirdBWEDate.Text, txtThirdBWEDate.Text)

   dates.Add(BWE1)
   dates.Add(BWE2)
   dates.Add(BWE3)

   STBAEndDateDDL.DataSource = dates
   STBAEndDateDDL.DataBind()
```

At the line...

```
STBAEndDateDDL.DataSource = dates
```

It's telling me that there is a null reference exception for dates. Totally stumped by this. It has been a long day, but surely there is enough in my code for the Visual Studio to know what dates is. No?

Any thoughts anyone?
Many thanks.
DS

Comment: Where is this code being called from?

Comment: Also, can you copy / paste the specific error message?  It seems more likely that the DropDownList doesn't exist yet when this code is called, or something along those lines (since you clearly just initialized and populated "dates").

Comment: Just ran your code from a click event and it was fine, how are you entering your dates? Specifically the format. If you enter the date such as: 12/01/13 it works just fine...

Comment: @jadarnel27 - you were right. i had this code in the PreRender event and hadn't initialised the dropdownlist i was populating yet. thanks for the help!

Comment: @dstewart101 I went ahead and posted an answer to that effect then - I'm glad I could help!  You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code above, this line:

```
STBAEndDateDDL.DataSource = dates
```

couldn't possibly be throwing a NullReferenceException for `dates` - you clearly initialized and populated it properly.

The other possibility is that `STBAEndDateDDL` (presumably a DropDownList) is null, because your in a stage of the Page life cycle where it doesn't exist / hasn't been initiliazed yet.  That seems like the most likely culprit.